# mysql query to build three tables into a matrix

Tags: mysql

Ok, this one is making my brain hurt:

I have three tables.  `Equipment`, `Site`, and `Permissions`.  An equipment master, a site master, and a list of what equipment is available at what site.

Equipment: EquipId, Description
Site:  SiteID, Site Name
EquipPerm: SiteId, EquipId

I need to generate a grid of those three in a single SQL statement:

If EquipPerm contains the corresponding SiteId and EquipId then True:

```
EquipPerm1 | SiteId1 | EquipId1 |
EquipPerm2 | SiteId1 | EquipId2 |
EquipPerm3 | SiteId2 | EquipId2 |
EquipPerm4 | SiteId3 | EquipId3 |
EquipPerm5 | SiteId2 | EquipId4 |
```

The desired SQL would produce the following:

```
|  Equipment | SiteId1 | SiteId2  | SiteId3 |
|- EquipId1 -|- true --|- false --|- false -|
|- EquipId2 -|- true --|- true ---|- false -|
|- EquipId3 -|- false -|- false --|- true --|
|- EquipId4 -|- false -|- true ---|- false -|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prepared statement to build up a query dynamically.

```
set @sql = null;

select group_concat(distinct concat('sum(if(a.siteid="',siteid,'",1,0))>0 `',siteid,'`')) 
from equipment_site
into @sql;

set @sql = concat('select a.equipid, ', @sql, '
                   from equipment_site a 
                   group by a.equipid');

prepare st from @sql;
execute st;
deallocate prepare st;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecbe/38)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What happens when site4 is added?  I don't want to have to update the SQL statement every time a site is added to the master.

Comment: Yup, I'm a dork.  I get it now...  Thank you.
Say I wanted to save the result of that query as a view...